# ¿Cómo traducir "assets" en "Java script assets" o "CSS assets"?

Tags: traducción, inglés

"Assets" son "activos" en castellano, menos frecuente "posesiones", pero ninguna de estas dos traducciones me cuadra en "CSS or Java script assets", ¿hay alguna traducción para esto? Según entiendo, serían algo así como las extensiones en CSS o Java script, pero puedo estar equivocado...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Siempre se ha usado *recurso* (*resource*) para referirse a cualquier archivo que no es de código, pero que es necesario para que funcione un programa (configuración, imagen, colecciones datos que no varían...)

Últimamente se utiliza *asset* para lo mismo, y la gente se pregunta [cuál es la diferencia](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/100203/whats-the-difference-between-an-asset-and-a-resource). Para complicar las cosas, hay entornos en los que se usan ambos conceptos y la gente se pregunta [dónde poner cada cosa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583608/difference-between-res-and-assets-directories). En la práctica, la distinción entre *resource* y *asset* es totalmente arbitraria, y cada entorno de desarrollo tiene sus convenciones al respecto, como ilustra el caso de Android del anterior enlace.

Yendo a la traducción, el par [*resource*/*asset* en inglés](https://wikidiff.com/resource/asset) me parece perfectamente equivalente al par *recurso*/*activo* en español. Con *recurso* nunca ha habido problema de traducción y, en principio, tampoco lo habría con *activo*.

¿O sí?

Siempre ha estado claro que los *recursos* se guardan en el directorio `resources` o `res`. Pero los *activos* (que, como decíamos, son la misma cosa) se guardan en el directorio `assets`. En el uso diario no veo a ningún programador usando la palabra *activo* ni ninguna otra traducción. En la práctica, lo que se suele hacer es evitar por completo la traducción [[1](https://blog.artegrafico.net/la-importancia-del-directorio-assets), [2]](https://javadesde0.com/analizando-la-estructura-del-directorio-src-de-un-proyecto-de-angular/), no por evitar el problema, sino porque se considera que  `assets` es un directorio y los nombres de directorio no se traducen.

Comment: Que buena respuesta. +1

Comment: "Qué buena respuesta" respuesta como dice el amigo @DGaleano, pero, ¿por qué dices que los nombres de directorios no se traducen?, ¿es una regla entre programadores? y ¿se aplica solo en desarrollo de software?, es que más de alguna vez he visto el nombre de algún directorio en castellano....

Comment: Los directorios pueden tener cualquier nombre, pero lo normal es seguir la convención habitual en cada ámbito de trabajo. Los directorios "resources" o "assets" son ejemplos de ello.
Windows, por ejemplo "localiza" (traduce) los nombres de algunos directorios, como "descargas" o "documentos", pero en realidad duplica los nombres, porque siguen también existiendo "downloads" o "documents". De este modo, si alguien escribe un programa que tiene que acceder a uno de ellos, no tiene que andar pensando en cómo puede estar traducido.